# Compare list of dictionaries with a single dictionary print difference

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

Lets say i have a list of dictionaries such as:

```
l1 = [{'ATP=15': 'ATP=15', 'PAN=10':'PAN=10', 'YUP="1230"':'YUP="1230"', 'DATA=45':'DATA=45'}, 
      {'ATP=13': 'ATP=13', 'PAN=10':'PAN=10', 'YUP="1220"':'YUP="1220"', 'DATA=42':'DATA=42'},
      {'ATP=12': 'ATP=12', 'PAN=10':'PAN=10', 'YUP="1220"':'YUP="1220"', 'DATA=43':'DATA=43'}]
```

and i have this single dictionary:

```
d2 = {'ATP': '15', 'PAN': '10', 'DATA': '45'}
```

My goal is to compare each entry in `d2` with each dictionary entry in `l1` and print out if they're equal or not.

We can also see that the dictionary in `l1` does has an extra entry called `YUP` we need to take into count that and print out that `yup` does not exist in `d2`.

so if we had an output it would go something like:

In dictionary A *(`l1[0]`)* `ATP, PAN, DATA` are correct however `YUP` does not appear in `d2` therefore is incorrect. In Dictionary B *(`l1[1]`)*, `ATP, DATA` are incorrect, `PAN` is correct, and `YUP` does not appear in `d2` therefore is incorrect. And so on, looping through however many dictionaries are in `l1`. *In my example we have three but there might be more or less*

What I've tried is the following:

```
 l1 = [{'ATP=15': 'ATP=15', 'PAN=10':'PAN=10', 'YUP="1230"':'YUP="1230"', 'DATA=45':'DATA=45'}, 
          {'ATP=13': 'ATP=13', 'PAN=10':'PAN=10', 'YUP="1220"':'YUP="1220"', 'DATA=42':'DATA=42'},
          {'ATP=12': 'ATP=12', 'PAN=10':'PAN=10', 'YUP="1220"':'YUP="1220"', 'DATA=43':'DATA=43'}]

 d2 = {'ATP': '15', 'PAN': '10', 'DATA': '45'}

 for i, d1 in enumerate(l1):
    for key in d1:
        if key in d2:
            if i == d2[i]:
                print '{} == {}'.format(key, d1[key])
            else:
                print '{} != {}'.format(key, d1[key])
        else:
            print '{} does not exist'.format(d1[key])
```

But I do not understand how to correctly loop through the list of dictionaries and correctly compare each entry to `d2`

If this is too generic or broad I will add more details if you need them.

Comment: Sure thing ill edit my question. And answer you other question, my current program is that my current code does not find any keys in `d2` and just executes `print '{} does not exist'.format(d1[key])` when clearly there are keys in `l1` that match keys in `d2`

Comment: The code you have now doesn't make sense. `i` is the index of `d1` within `l1`, but you're using it as a key to `d2` and ignoring `key`... I think you wanted `if d1[key] == d2[key]:` (i.e. *"if both dictionaries contain the same value for this key"*).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Alright I edited my code, sorry i tend to get super confused with loops, im still learning how to correctly literate. It seems that changing my `if` statement to your suggestion appears to give me the same results and only executes the `else` statement.

Comment: Well, *is* e.g. `'ATP=15' in {'ATP': '15', 'PAN': '10', 'DATA': '45'}`? Your two sets of dictionaries **don't actually match**, so you shouldn't be surprised by the outcome.

Comment: Also, is the `key: value`  format in `l1` the way you have presented it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe So i need to either my `l1` or `d2` to match each others format. Sorry i completely missed that. Ill see what I can do towards reformating them

Comment: @DimitrisJim Yeah I need to reformat that `key: value` correctly now to match my `d2` i had completely over looked that

Comment: your dictionary l1 has incorrect keys and values i guess